# Where to go for missions in Crash Time II?

Tags: crash-time-2

Okay, I started playing [Crash Time II](http://store.steampowered.com/app/11390/) and I've already noticed the flags indicating there are still missions to do with that certain car.

For some missions you get a message over the radio, asking for assistance, and others require you to drive to a certain location (discovered by accident) to be able to start them. I have not been able to find a way to quickly see where the starting point of those missions are located (besides randomly driving around, and hoping you find the one.)

Is there a way to quickly know where to go for a certain mission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1722873000) post has suggestions on what to do if you are trying to find missions and are unsure how to find them.

> 1. You aren't using the correct character or vehicle. - While you are in the vehicle selection menu use your left/right arrow keys to select
>    different characters. Watch out for a red flag to the right of
>    vehicles. If there is one that means that there is a mission available
>    for it.
> 2. You have already started the case but switched to another one. - I'm not actually sure if this can actually happen, but in case it has
>    just go to the Cases menu and select the case you want to continue
>    doing.
> 3. You are on the wrong map. - There are two maps in Crash Time 2 - the city map and the highway map. If you can't start a case then
>    travel/spawn at the other map and try there.
> 4. The case you are trying to start doesn't start automatically. - Some cases require you to drive to a certain case marker in order to
>    start them. If that's the case, enter the minimap and try to find the
>    marker.